# How do I handle optional XML attributes in VBA?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, error-handling

I've written some code to import some data from an XML file into excel, it works up until it tries to read attributes that don't exist; they are optional in the file and I can't add them in so I need to handle it in the code.

I've tried handling the objects with `If Is Not Nothing`, but that doesn't work, neither does `If <> ""` or `If <> Null` with no luck.

If anyone can give me any assistance I would be extremely grateful.

```
Public Sub import()

    Dim oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim fSuccess As Boolean
    Dim oRoot As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim oSoftkey As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim oAttributes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap
    Dim oSoftkeyName As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim oSoftkeyDescriptor As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim oSoftkeyStyleName As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Dim oChildren As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim oChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim intI As Integer
    On Error GoTo HandleErr

    Set oDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    oDoc.async = False
    oDoc.validateOnParse = False
    fSuccess = oDoc.Load(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\keys.xml")

    If Not fSuccess Then
      GoTo ExitHere
    End If

    intI = 2
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Name"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "TextDescriptor"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "StyleName"

    ' Get the root of the XML tree.
    ' Set oRoot = oDoc.DocumentElement
    Set oRoot = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("//IMS_Softkeys")

    ' Each IMS_Softkey in IMS_Softkeys
    For Each oSoftkey In oRoot.ChildNodes

      Set oAttributes = oSoftkey.Attributes

      Set oSoftkeyName = oAttributes.getNamedItem("Name")
      Set oSoftkeyDescriptor = oAttributes.getNamedItem("TextDescriptor")
      Set oSoftkeyStyleName = oAttributes.getNamedItem("StyleName")

      ActiveSheet.Cells(intI, 1).Value = oSoftkeyName.Text

      'Can't handle optional attribute "TextDescriptor" or "SoftkeyStyle"
      ActiveSheet.Cells(intI, 2).Value = oSoftkeyDescriptor.Text
      ActiveSheet.Cells(intI, 3).Value = oSoftkeyStyleName.Text

      intI = intI + 1
    Next oSoftkey
ExitHere:
    Exit Sub
HandleErr:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitHere
    Resume
End Sub
```

An example XML file (keys.xml):

```
<BATCH>
  <IMS_BATCH>
    <IMS_Softkeys>
      <IMS_Softkey Name="Donut" StyleName="Mer-Green-Yellow" TextDescriptor="1 Donut" />
      <IMS_Softkey Name="Hotdog" StyleName="Mer-White-Black" TextDescriptor="11&quot; Hotdog" />
      <IMS_Softkey Name="Coke_Image" TextDescriptor="Coke" />
      <IMS_Softkey Name="DietCoke_Image" StyleName="Style for DietCocaCola" />
    </IMS_Softkeys>
  </IMS_BATCH>
</BATCH>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are Objects and in VBA you check if they are *empty* (*been aassigned*) using the following syntax

`If Not (Object Is Nothing) Then`

So if you want to check if the attributes were retrieved and assigned from XML then you could:

```
' Print only if the `oSoftKeyDescriptor` is not nothing
If Not (oSoftkeyDescriptor Is Nothing) Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(intI, 2).Value = oSoftkeyDescriptor.Text
End If

If Not (oSoftkeyStyleName Is Nothing) Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(intI, 3).Value = oSoftkeyStyleName.Text
End If
```

and I believe this is the result your are after

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using `If Not Is Nothing` wrong. It works perfectly now.

Comment: @sab0tage I am glad I could help. On Stack Overflow we say thank you by [accepting answers which helped us](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). There's a green checkmark next to the answer on the left which you tick :)